# "A revised version of this preprint was accepted" Meaning?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, paper-submission

I would like to know what does "a revised version of this preprint was accepted for the journal ESD." mean? Does it mean that there is 100 percent chance that the revised version of this paper will accepted and the final paper will also be accepted? Or there is a chance of getting the paper rejected?

Comment: "accepted" should really be "accepted for publication" in such sentences.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means that in the time interval from when the preprint was uploaded and now, the paper has been revised and this revised version has been accepted for publication at the journal. In other words, the revision and acceptance have **already happened**, though the journal may not (or may) have published it yet.

Answer (score 7):

"Accepted by X" means the revised article has made it through peer review and will be published by journal X, unless some very unusual and unforeseen circumstance arises (for example if it is discovered there is a major problem that invalidates the entire paper which was missed by the referees). The accepted version may still be slightly different from the published version due to edits made in the proof stage (e.g., copy-editors may find typos or undefined acronyms).

Comment: My reading is that the accepted version can be substantially different from the preprint.

Comment: @VladimirF The version before peer review can be quite different from the accepted version, while the accepted version should be very similar to the published version. Different people/fields have different standards for what gets posted on a preprint server (eg some people will post an accepted or published version), but if the version on the preprint server is before peer review then yes, it can be quite different from the final version.